# Need to spread a data.frame that has character and numeric values in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have several dataframes in a list, and I am trying to join them using map in purrr. I am using `full_join` at the end because they don't all have the same columns, as an example of something that works I have the following:

```
DF1 <- structure(list(scrubbed_species_binomial = c("Solanum montanum", 
"Solanum montanum", "Solanum montanum"), trait_name = c("whole plant woodiness", 
"whole plant growth form", "whole plant growth form diversity"
), trait_value = c("herbaceous", "Herb", "Herb")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("scrubbed_species_binomial", 
"trait_name", "trait_value"))
```

When I use tidyverse to separate traits

```
DF1 %>% distinct() %>% spread(trait_name, trait_value)
```

I get the following

```
scrubbed_species_binomial whole plant growth form whole plant growth form diversity whole plant woodiness
1          Solanum montanum                    Herb                              Herb            herbaceous
```

### The problem

Some of the data.frames have numeric traits that are repeated, but since trait value is a character column, when I try to use `spread` or `summarize_if(is.numeric)` I get errors

#### First attempt

```
DF2 <- structure(list(scrubbed_species_binomial = c("Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum"), trait_name = c("whole plant growth form diversity", 
"leaf area per leaf dry mass", "leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", 
"leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", "leaf thickness", "leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", 
"leaf thickness", "leaf thickness", "leaf area per leaf dry mass", 
"leaf area per leaf dry mass", "whole plant growth form"), trait_value = 
c("Herb", 
"1.84229918938836e-05", "1.913", "2.166", "0.2506", "1.898", 
"0.2358", "0.2535", "2.21729490022173e-05", "2.07770621234157e-05", 
"Herb")), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame", .Names = 
c("scrubbed_species_binomial", 
"trait_name", "trait_value"))
```

#### First try

when I try this:

```
DF2 %>% distinct() %>% spread(trait_name, trait_value)
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (2, 9, 10), (3, 4, 6), (5, 7, 8)
```

And if I try to summarize if numeric it does not work either

Let me know what should I do

Comment: Before `spread`, you can add a row number to serve as a dummy ID. That way there will be a non-duplicate column like `spread` requires

Answer (score 1):

You would need to tell `spread` that duplicate `trait_name` should come in different rows so add `row_number()` before `spread` and you should be all set.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(scrubbed_species_binomial, trait_name) %>%
  mutate(row_idx = row_number()) %>%
  spread(trait_name, trait_value)
```

which gives

```
  scrubbed_species~ row_idx `leaf area per l~ `leaf dry mass ~ `leaf thickness` `whole plant gr~ `whole plant gr~
  <chr>               <int> <chr>             <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 Solanum peruvian~       1 1.84229918938836~ 1.913            0.2506           Herb             Herb            
2 Solanum peruvian~       2 2.21729490022173~ 2.166            0.2358           <NA>             <NA>            
3 Solanum peruvian~       3 2.07770621234157~ 1.898            0.2535           <NA>             <NA>
```

**Sample data:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(scrubbed_species_binomial = c("Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", "Solanum peruvianum", 
"Solanum peruvianum"), trait_name = c("whole plant growth form diversity", 
"leaf area per leaf dry mass", "leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", 
"leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", "leaf thickness", "leaf dry mass per leaf fresh mass", 
"leaf thickness", "leaf thickness", "leaf area per leaf dry mass", 
"leaf area per leaf dry mass", "whole plant growth form"), trait_value = c("Herb", 
"1.84229918938836e-05", "1.913", "2.166", "0.2506", "1.898", 
"0.2358", "0.2535", "2.21729490022173e-05", "2.07770621234157e-05", 
"Herb")), .Names = c("scrubbed_species_binomial", "trait_name", 
"trait_value"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a great solution, because it creates the appearance of associations where there aren't any, but this might get you what you need.  It's along the same lines as @camille is saying but fleshed-out a bit.

```
DF2 %>% 
  group_by(trait_name) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  spread(trait_name, trait_value, convert = TRUE) %>%
  fill(everything())
```